# Python COM Server for using Google API

Tags: python, vbscript, server, com

I am registering a Python COM server so I can use it in VBScript.
Whenever i register a server which does not use google api then I am able to instantiate the COM object in VBS.
The code looks like this.
`

```
import pythoncom, win32com.server.register

class Python_For_VBS:
    _public_methods_ = ['Hello']
    _reg_progid_ = "PythonForVBS.Utilities"
    _reg_clsid_ = pythoncom.CreateGuid()

    def Hello(self, item=None):
        import ctypes
        MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW
        MessageBox(None, 'Hello', 'Window title', 0)
        msg = "Hello"
        return msg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine (Python_For_VBS)
```

`

It gets registered fine and also am able to use it in VBS.

but when i register this (this is the sample code from developers.google.com.

`

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

import pythoncom, win32com.server.register, ctypes
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'QTest'

class GAPI:
    _public_methods_ = ['returnfiles']
    _reg_progid_ = "GAPI.Utilities"
    _reg_clsid_ = '{FDB80AAF-D3AD-417C-ADBA-E93D7FF59E86}'

    def get_credentials(self, item=None):
        #import ctypes
        #MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW
        #MessageBox(None, 'get_credentials', 'Window title', 0)
        store = Storage('Storage.json')
        creds = store.get()
        if not creds or creds.invalid:
            flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
            if flags:
                credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
            else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
                credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        return creds

    def returnfiles (self, item=None):
        #import ctypes
        MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW
        MessageBox(None, 'returnfiles', 'Window title', 0)
        creds = self.get_credentials()
        http = creds.authorize(httplib2.Http())
        service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

        results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10,fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
        items = results.get('files', [])
        msg = "Files:"
        if not items:
            msg = msg + " No Items"
        else:
            for item in items:
                msg = msg + " File name : " + item['name'] + " ID : " + item['id']
        return msg
if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine (GAPI)
```

`

It registers fine but when i use CreateObject("GAPI.Utilities") in VBS then i get error 80004005.

I am using pyhthon36-32 (32bit).
I have tried pyhthon36 (64 bit) then also it does not work it gives me error like "System could find the module"

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your error message *System could not find the module* is because just installing 64-bit Python is unlikely to solve anything. If you do that, then you must also install 64-bit versions of *everything* you have been working with up to that point, including `pythoncom`, `win32com`, `oauth2client`, etc.

Comment: What happens if you test your COM server from Python? Like this:  `mygapi = win32com.client.Dispatch("GAPI.Utilities")`. That may help to localize the problem.

Comment: let me try this.

Comment: When i use python COM client then it works.
So what could possibly be going wrong?

Comment: Urk. My Python is rather better than my VB and from your test it appears that this is a VB problem. That error number appears to be *unspecified error* but one issue that does come up if I google it is *something to do with permissions*. Try running your VB client as administrator. That might at least give a more useful error message.

Comment: I used VBSEdit 32 bit and it could instantiate the COM object.
I will try uninstalling everything and put 64 bit of everything and see if it works.

Comment: I could be wrong but I think COM is just about the only part of Windows that is *not* bitness-sensitive.

Comment: I just uninstalled and installed 64 bit of Python and pywin32 and it worked.
Thanks for your help.